# how to code for expired referesh token google api calendar

Tags: php, cakephp, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using cakephp4 with [google api calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api). I have connected with Oauth2 and that seems to work fine in viewing calendar events etc.

My issue is that I have code to deal with access token being expired as I can update this but I am unclear in how to deal with expired refresh token?

I am likely to get an invalid_grant error. I know refresh token expired in 200days if not on Test project. I can code for that but invalid_grant requests can come a few ways

How to CODE for an expired REFRESH token so i dont get invalid_grant error?

```
 //From php docs for calendar api below avoids the issue

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php  /*code from google but nothing on refresh token expiring ? */
if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
  
          
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $token= $client->getAccessToken();       
            
            $jtoken=json_encode($token);


   //this didnt clairfy things with any code
   https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35

  // in Client.php in google add on code that is placed in vendor folder, it doesnt go into refresh token expired? As an example
    public function getRefreshToken()
  {
    if (isset($this->token['refresh_token'])) {
      return $this->token['refresh_token'];
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the most common cause of an invalid grant error is your refresh token expiring. Your refresh token is probably expiring because your application is still in the testing phase.  Applications in the testing phase will have their refresh tokens expired after seven days. Once it has been released to production your refresh tokens will stop expiring.  As long as you use it once every six months the expiration on the refresh token keeps resetting making it valid indefinitely unless the user removes your access.

To fix your issue delete the refresh token you have now and your application should then request access of the user again. You will then have a new refresh token which will work for seven days.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the 7 day limit for Refresh  Tokens on testing phase. That doesnt answer the question as i need to code for the error. Doesnt it throw an error after 200days meaning i need to keep check of the date from when the refresh token was created?

Comment: whether it is in test/production mode is not relevant as do i simply check the time elapsed in code since refresh token was created?

Comment: Assuming your app is in production.  Refresh tokens dont expire after 200 day unless your application hasn't used it in that time.   If you have then the 200 days continues to be extended indefinitely.  Unless the user revokes your access.    If you haven't used it in 200 days or the user revokes your access, then a different error message is thrown and the php client library will handle this error by request access of the user again (showing the consent screen).

Comment: The issue is that the error message that is being thrown by the 7 day limit is not handled properly by the client library I have logged this as an issue they just haven't fixed it.

Comment: TBH i would just catch the error and request access again.   Great idea for a tutorial see if i cant create one next week.

Comment: hi could you place code here to catch the error for a  ? A lot of people would like to know how this done with code (php). Not using the access for 200days or revoking access is an error to catch i am unsure of the code

Comment: you don't need to catch the one for not using it for 200 days the client library will do it for you

Comment: to catch the error though for this with code is ?catch(Exception $e) {
    // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
    debug( 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage() );
}